# Average Speed based on table data POWER BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a table in power BI with values like that :

[image]

and I need to calculate the diference in time

[image]

and show a measure with average speed (time / x) with DAX formula

[image]

what I tried :

```
metric = (sumx(table,[date] - EARLIER([date])) * [x])/COUNTROW([data])
```

but EARLIRER doesn't work

Comment: Your expected result number 3.75 [m] has the dimension length and is a duration weighted distance. The average speed based on your sample data is 2.125 [m/s], and your metric formula would give 6 [ms], if the DAX was working. None of that is compatible. Please explain!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- How to calculate the difference in time

```
dif = DATEDIFF(MAXX(FILTER(All('Table'), 'Table'[date] < EARLIER('Table'[date])), 'Table'[date]), 'Table'[date], SECOND)
```

- How to calculate a measure for the average speed

```
average = SUMX('Table', 'Table'[x (m)] * 'Table'[dif]) / SUM('Table'[dif])
```

Those formulas will help you get the correct output/result.
[image]